# (hook_menu_alter) override the same path twice

Tags: 7, routes

I have created a custom module which implements the [hook_menu_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) in order to override those two paths and to add my own access control logic:

`$items['taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term/edit']['access callback']`

`$items['taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term/edit']['access arguments']`

Looking for an out of the box solution I found this module [vppr](https://www.drupal.org/project/vppr) which overrides the exact same paths adding its own logic.

The point is that if I have both modules enabled - **vppr** module and **my custom module** -  the `['access callback']` from my custom module is never fired. If I disable the **vppr** module my module is working fine.

Is that possible, two different modules can't override the same path or I'm missing something, and why the `['access callback']` from the contrid module is executed over mine?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can only be one set of metadata for a single path. Hooks are invoked sequentially, so yes, if you have another module altering the same path, either yours or theirs will 'win'; never both.

You can control the order hooks are called in using the 'weight' column in the system table, or through the use of [`hook_module_implements_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7).

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer(s) is/are really helpful. I could never imagine something like that: "either yours or theirs will 'win'; never both.". The proposed hook seems to add some order in the hooks chaos but it also seems a little scary in terms of implementation, at least for non experienced developers, thanks again!